# My MacBook Pro periodically displays ads in a banner on the top right that says "Breaking Apple News"

Tags: macbook-pro

I have OSX 10.9.5.  It seems to happen once or twice within a few minutes after I come out of sleep.  A smallish banner on the top right kind of slides in place.  It's always text that starts with "Breaking Apple News" and then it advertises something.

Is this Malware, or did Apple really stoop to this level?  If it's really Apple SW doing this, is it at least optional to disable it?  I paid for my MacBook Pro.  I don't think slide in ads are appropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have accidentally allowed a website to send you push notifications. If you use Safari, go into Preferences > Notifications, and see if you've allowed any sites to give you notifications.

Comment: Well I did indeed have a push notification allowed according to this menu.  It had a little icon that looked like the same one that keeps appearing in these ads.  I gave you an up vote because your hypothesis is helpful whether or not is solves my problem.  In a day or 2 if no more ads appear I'll give you the check mark as well.  ;)

Answer (score -1):

The sliding banner in the upper right of my MacBook Pro was a nuisance, too. To eliminate it, I clicked the apple icon in the upper menu bar and selected "preferences". In preferences, select "notifications". In notifications, highlite each item (such as Pinterest) from the left display box and un-check it in the right display area. You must do this for each site that is appearing in the sliding ad boxes on your machine. They will appear in the left display box when you go to notifications. I am running High Sierra OS

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your answer provides the same info to the answer already provided and approved.  How is your answer different from that one?